# linux nasm assembly isolating characters in a string

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

If I had a string declared like this:

```
message db "ABCDEFGHIJ",0
```

how could I create a pointer that would allow me to point to a specific character in this string, such as the 'A' character. And also, how could I create a loop that would allow me to increment the pointer and as a result, cycle through the entire string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    mov ecx, message ; Masm would use "offset"
top:
    mov al, [ecx] ; get a character
    inc ecx  ; get ready for next one
    cmp al, 0  ; end of string?
    jz done
; do something intelligent with al
    jmp top
done:
```

Comment: Simple yet effective. Thank you.